# InitState with setState or FutureBuilder? Which method is better to display data from a database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app displays data gathered from a SQLite database in a `ListView`. I could use a `FutureBuilder` to wait for the data to be fetched and then return a ListView. Or I could set a callback to when my data is loaded in `InitState()` and then `setState()` with the data loaded. I was able to use both ways and display a `CircularProgressIndicator` until data was loaded. Which of these ways is better that I should continue to use in the rest of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` is a widget that builds only its children, whereas `setState` inside a callback block in `initState` does the rebuild of the entire screen. It is always better to rebuild only portion of the widget tree to gain on performance, than to rebuild entire screen when data is received.

Comment: In addition to this, if you want to update some certain part of the screen, you can make it a separate dart module/widget and include it inside the screen where you need it. And pass functions and/or use GlobalScope to exchange data to and from widgets.
Using setState can highly degrade your app performance if the screen has a lot of widgets (Say a list view) and you are updating your screen again and again. One such example can be a music player where you update your music progress bar every second, you done need to rebuild/calculate your list every second.